# How to modify legend order in two stack bar plot combined

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, legend

I am trying to arrange two stack bar plots into one figure with a common legend and I want the legend to be ordered as A, B and C. The dummy data represents two data sets, individually the stacked bar plots are coded so that the highest "perc" for each "name" is plotted at the bottom and the smallest at the top. This alters the order of the legend for each individual plot and for the combined which I believe takes the legend of the first plot. I only want to modify the order of the legend.

I tried to add "scale_x_discrete (limits=c("A", "B", "C"))  but it won´t work.  If any one could help me please!

Thanks in advance !
Cheers,
a newbie coder.

```
require(ggplot2)

name1 <- c('A','B','C','A','B','C')
name2 <- c('A','B','C','A','B','C')
datet1 <- c("11/08/1999","11/08/1999","11/08/1999","11/12/1998","11/12/1998","11/12/1998")
datet2 <- c("11/08/1999","11/08/1999","11/08/1999","11/12/1998","11/12/1998","11/12/1998")
perc1 <- c(5, 20, 40, 20, 10, 5)
perc2 <- c(15, 10, 5, 5, 5, 30)

data1 <- data.frame(name1, perc1,datet1)
data2 <- data.frame(name2, perc2,datet2)

data1$datet1 <- as.Date(data1$datet1, format="%d/%m/%Y")
data2$datet2 <- as.Date(data2$datet2,format="%d/%m/%Y")

mydatet1<-format(data1$datet1, "%d %b %Y")
date_factort1<-factor(mydatet1, levels = rev(unique(mydatet1)),ordered = TRUE)

mydatet2<-format(data2$datet2, "%d %b %Y")
date_factort2<-factor(mydatet2, levels = rev(unique(mydatet2)),ordered = TRUE)

colours<-c("A"= "#fdb863", 
           "B"="#b2abd2", 
           "C"="#5e3c99")

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
barplot_1<-ggplot(data1,aes(fill=reorder(name1,+perc1),y=perc1, 
                              x=date_factort1))+
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=colours)
print(barplot_1)

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
barplot_2<-ggplot(data2,aes(fill=reorder(name2,+perc2),y=perc2, 
                            x=date_factort2))+
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=colours)

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
combine_plot<-ggarrange(barplot_2, barplot_1,
                          labels = c("a", "b"),ncol = 1, nrow = 2,
                          common.legend = TRUE, legend = "bottom")
```

[See the common legend is plotted as C, A , B. I want it to be A, B, C and to keep the order of the plots as they´ve been arranged)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7D5e.png)

Comment: Hm. When I run your code I get a legend in the right order A, B, C.

Comment: Hi Stefan,  I get the correct order in barplot_1 but barplot_2 and the combined plot are different.  The common legend is ordered as B, A and C. I want to change it to A, B, C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can treat the names as factor with custom levels, A, B and C. By default, the levels would be ordered based on the first appearance.

Here is the code:

```
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
barplot_1<-ggplot(data1,aes(fill=factor(reorder(name1,+perc1), levels = c("A", "B", "C")),y=perc1, 
                            x=date_factort1))+
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=colours)


# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
barplot_2<-ggplot(data2,aes(fill = factor(reorder(name2,+perc2), levels = c("A", "B", "C")),y=perc2, 
                            x=date_factort2))+
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=colours)

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
combine_plot<-ggarrange(barplot_2, barplot_1,
                        labels = c("a", "b"),ncol = 1, nrow = 2,
                        common.legend = TRUE, legend = "bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Mohanasundaram, this is correct and I believe it's the best way to represent both graphs. I did notice that "fill=reorder(name1,+perc1)" is only working on the first date/bar of each graph which will define the order of the next one. Is there any way to extend this reordering to the rest of the data plotted?  Thanks a lot!